# SBT add checkstyle, findbugs and pmd when running tests

Tags: playframework, sbt, checkstyle, findbugs, pmd

I have found how to add PMD, findBugs and checkstyle in a SBT project, but I would like these tools to be triggered during all builds.

How can I get, for instance,

```
sbt checkStyle
```

to be triggered by

```
sbt compile
```

?

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample build.sbt with the findbugs4sbt plugin that makes sure it will run before compile:

```
import de.johoop.findbugs4sbt.FindBugs

FindBugs.findbugsSettings

compile <<= (compile in Compile).dependsOn(FindBugs.findbugs)
```

Comment: Thx @johanandren, but do you know how to do it with 1) multiple tasks and 2) tasks defined in Build.Scala ?

Comment: dependsOn is a varargs method so you can just append keys, you could do the same in Build.scala except that then you would have to put the override of compile into your sequence of settings (if this feels unclear I strongly advice you to read up on the sbt documentation or possibly get the sbt in action book to get more comfortable with the basics)